# syntax error in Insert mysql using Minus

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, bigdata

I have the syntax error in mysql Insert command , do you have any suggestion?
Thank you in advance

```
    insert = "INSERT INTO dbpedia_untyped_instance SELECT resource FROM stat_resource MINUS (SELECT resource FROM dbpedia_types UNION SELECT resource FROM dbpedia_disambiguations)";
    try {
        stmt.execute(insert);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error inserting into untyped instance table");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't currently support `MINUS`.

As a workaround, you can use an exclusion join.

Something like this would work for you (another option is to use `NOT EXISTS`):

```
SELECT RESOURCE
FROM stat_resource
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbpedia_types 
  ON dbpedia_types.resource = stat_resource.resource
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbpedia_disambiguations 
  ON dbpedia_disambiguations.resource = stat_resource.resource
WHERE dbpedia_types.resource IS NULL
  AND dbpedia_disambiguations.resource IS NULL
```